# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 After Adding API 23

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm using Eclipse, I implemented **ffmpeg** for video compression [from this link.](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html)  Actually this is for Studio but I converted given library for Eclipse, but ffmpeg required API-23 so I added API-23 from sdk manager and from that movement I'm getting "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536" error After Adding API 23. I found 4-5 questions asked before for this problem but yet not found any satisfactory answer. So any help will really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because the limitation of 65K method exceeds.

You need to check that how many libraries or .jar files you have added in your project.

This error mostly occurs because of your google-play-services libs project. If you are using "google-play-services" lib project then try the following solution---

```
1] go in the google-play-service-lib project
2] go in libs
3] unzip the file google-play-services.jar
4] go in the the unzipped folder and remove all folders that you don't need (i.e. if you need Analytics, you can remove ads, games, maps, wallet, drive, etc.)
5]zip again such a folder (that now contains only the needed libraries) together with the MANIFEST folder
6]use such new jar with your project.
```